# Given this script, how can I place the submenu to the left of the main menu?

Tags: javascript, css

see this script please:

```
<style>
.rightnav_menu
{
    width: 152px;
    height: 294px;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #cae9eb;
}

.rightnav_menu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 152px;
}

.rightnav_menu ul li
{
    position: relative;
}

.rightnav_menu ul li a
{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #DCDBF9;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px;
}

.rightnav_menu ul li a:link, .rightnav_menu ul li a:visited, .rightnav_menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #012D58;
}

.rightnav_menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
}

.rightnav_menu ul li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 152px;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}



* html .rightnav_menu ul li { float: left; height: 1%; }
* html .rightnav_menu ul li a { height: 1%; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Nested Side Bar Menu (Mar 20th, 09)
//By Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/

var menuids=["sidebarmenu"] //Enter id(s) of each Side Bar Menu's main UL, separated by commas

function initsidebarmenu() {
    for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++) {
        var ultags = document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul");

        for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++) {
            ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className += " subfolderstyle"

            if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[i]) {
                //if this is a first level submenu
                //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
                ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth+"px" 
            } else {
                //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
                //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
                ultags[t].style.left = ultags[t-1].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth + "px"
            }

            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover = function() {
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block"
            }

            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout = function() {
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none"
            }
        }
        for (var t=ultags.length-1; t>-1; t--) {
            //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
            ultags[t].style.visibility = "visible"
            ultags[t].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", initsidebarmenu, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", initsidebarmenu)

</script>
```

This is the style and the script.. and you can see an exapmle of what it does here:

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/267332783/css_menue_trail.html
```

I'm writing in Arabic and I tried to modify this script to suit my style above to make the sub menu appear at the left side of the item... please try it with me please

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Replace "left" width "right" in both the css and javascript code and then add dir="rtl" to the html-tag. Your header should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html dir="rtl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  ...
</head>
```

This seems to work for me, but then I don't know any arabic :-)

Here is a modified version: [css_menue_trail_arabic.html](http://kanino.net/css_menue_trail_arabic.html)